# How to Implement Webhooks for Google Contacts Updates and Creations

Tags: python, rest, google-cloud-platform

I am currently unable to locate any resources, and I have not found any information in the People API documentation regarding how to send data through a webhook when a contact is updated or created in Google Contacts.

I have thoroughly reviewed the documentation for the People API. My objective is to integrate Google Contacts into my application. Specifically, when a user integrates Google Contacts through my application and subsequently creates a contact in Google Contacts, I aim to synchronize that contact with my application's contact list.

The primary goal is to establish a mechanism wherein, upon creating a contact in Google Contacts, the relevant data is transmitted through a webhook to my application. Subsequently, this data should be stored in my application's database.

Comment: There is no "New Contact" trigger. My only idea is to scan/filter the contacts and compare the "Created Date" or similar fields. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder

Comment: Cant you give me full desciption how can i use that

Comment: I provided a link to the documentation. Since their is no API for what you want, take my suggestion and write code to emulate it.

Comment: i think that approach is related to cron job scheduling and it will be resoucrce consuming ..is not there any other way in python

Comment: You can either check the contacts manually for a new entry or you can schedule a periodic check. It is up to you to decide what you want to implement.

Comment: Is it related to google Addson

Comment: What is google Addson?